# how to decide if my variables shall be inside the class that extend StatefulWidget OR Starte<>?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a class QuizPage extends StatefulWidget,

and another class _QuizPageState extends State< QuizPage>

```
class QuizPage extends StatefulWidget {
  var HERE; // or over there ?
  @override
  _QuizPageState createState() => _QuizPageState();
}

class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {
  var HERE; // or over there ?    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {return Container();}
}
```

What's the difference if any?

> I'm new to flutter, but I noticed through the
>   examples I encountered that if I want to send ***anything*** through the
>   constructor, it has to be in the ***StatefulWidget*** and I can access it
>   inside the ***State*** by ***widget.anything***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables inside the `StatefulWidget` subclass *cannot* change over time. They must be declared as `final`, or else you'll have a warning.

Adding variables here should be done solely for parameters: Other widgets communicating with this one.

`State<T>` subclass has much more freedom on that topic. This is where you should put all your internal variables. Whether the change over time or not.